# events.js:183 throw Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: laravel, vue.js

The system cannot find the path specified.

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: spawn node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT
>       at notFoundError (D:\xampp\htdocs\learnlarvel\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
>       at verifyENOENT (D:\xampp\htdocs\learnlarvel\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
>       at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\xampp\htdocs\learnlarvel\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\iSkylarTechnology\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-14T11_40_34_967Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\iSkylarTechnology\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-14T11_40_35_155Z-debug.log

Comment: Try to explain what actually the error is and provide a clean code, with explanations, and one or more screenshots of the error

Comment: events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Comment: It's not clear, please

Comment: events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT
    at notFoundError (D:\xampp\htdocs\learnlarvel\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (D:\xampp\htdocs\learnlarvel\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\xampp\htdocs\learnlarvel\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12) how to solve this error this error is present when type command npm run dev

Answer (score 2):

Delete your `node_modules` folder and delete `package-lock.json`. Run `npm cache clear --force` and then `npm install`. Then try `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`.